# Laravel get a collection of relationship items

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm stuck on this what seems like a simple task.

**I have a User that has many Shops that have many Products..**

I'm trying to get all the Products for a certain User.

This is working, and is returning the Shops with their Products

```
\Auth::user()->shops()->with('products')->get();
```

But I need a Collection of only the Products. I tried the following but it's messing up the Query

```
\Auth::user()->shops()->with('products')->select('products.*')->get();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with doing `Products::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get()`? Do you need access to the shops also?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You can use this :

```
\Auth::user()->shops()->with('products')->get()->pluck('products')->flatten();
```

if you don't want replicate, you can use `->unique()`

If you want to directly work on a query (for performances):

```
 Product::whereHas('shops', function($query){
    $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
 })->get();
```

Comment: Perfect! Just Perfect! Didn't know about the pluck

Comment: Cheers! This just saved me from a very roundabout optimization path.

Comment: Is it possible to use `products` in another query? I mean, how to paginate those `products`... Thanks.

Comment: I edit my answer to answer this question :)

Answer (score 14):

what you need is a relationship between the User Model and the Product Model ..

this is possible using `hasManyThrough` relationship ..

**USER MODEL**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Shop')
}
```

now, you can access all the user's products with

```
Auth::user()->products;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is, there will also be Users that are a Supplier in, and don't have Shops.. So that will conflict then right.

Comment: then in your case .. your product model should have also have a user_id field in the database .. then change the return to `$this->hasMany('App\Product'); but this is not a good practice as you are bypassing the hierarchy of your model relations ..

Comment: Worth noting you can use ->with('relationship') to eager load that relationship

Answer (score 6):

In this case you can use [lazy eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading):

```
auth()->user()->load('shops.products');
```

To iterate over products:

```
@foreach (auth()->user()->shops as $shop)
    @foreach ($shop->products as $product)
        {{ $product->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you need just products:

```
Product::whereHas('shop', function ($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', auth()->id());
})->get();
```

In both cases, you'll have the same number of queries to DB, so I'd use the first example in a real app.

Comment: im not the one who downvoted this but i think this is because the OP is asking how to access products without using the shop ..

Comment: @Demonyowh your example creates queries for using `shops` table too, so it uses shops anyway.

Comment: @Notflip I've added another solution that uses `shop` relationship which is `belongsTo()` in the `Product` model.

Comment: @Demonyowh as you can see I've said about the queries in my comment.  BTW, in a real app, you'll need shops sooner or later.

Comment: im not the one who downvoted this .. it's just my assumptions .. i dont know why they downvoted this .. sorry ..

Comment: Your non-edited answer did not include the `whereHas` example. And the question asks for `the collection of ONLY the products`. If you load the shops of the users and the products of the shops, you will end up with a User object which has a Collection of shops and every shop with their separate product collections. That is not what the question asks. That is why I down voted your answer.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that your product model has the shop id stored, try the following:

```
Products::whereIn('id_shop',
    Shops::select('id')
    ->where('id_owner_user',Auth::user()->id)
    ->get())
->get()
```

It will retrieve a collection of products that belong to the list of shops which belong to the authenticated user

Comment: This doesn't use relationships or a join, this is just two SELECT queries one run inside the other as a parameter so is less efficient and not what OP asked

Comment: He said: "But I need a Collection of only the Products." if you make a join you are pulling two models

Comment: BTW, for those who downvoted, laravel relationships produce a query like mine and @DanielWaters I was reading today a lot about it and two select queries are faster than a join. Have a good coding mates