# How to select statement for showing data

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have table in mysql like this

```
-----------------------------
|id|warehouse_id|item_id|qty|
---|------------|-------|---|
|1 | 1          | 1     |10 |
|2 | 1          | 2     |23 |
|3 | 2          | 1     |45 |
|4 | 2          | 2     |66 |
|5 | 1          | 3     |44 |
```

How using select statement to show table what i want like this

```
------------------------------------------
|id|item_id|qty warehouse 1|qty warehouse 2
---|-------|---------------|-------------
|1 | 1     | 10            |45         |
|2 | 2     | 23            |66         |
|3 | 3     | 44            |0          |
```

i was trying using eloquent laravel like this

```
ItemStockModel::get()
```

thank you

Comment: You have only two warehouse or you have several ??

Comment: You should use Join query for this. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins

Comment: @scaisEdge i have several warehouse, can you help me ?

Comment: for several  warehouse in mysql  you should  manage the result server side .. (not by sql)

Comment: @scaisEdge how if i have only two warehouse, please give me example using sql or eloquent laravel

Comment: @ShaileshMatariya it is only one table

Comment: @user8210918 yes, you can join same table multiple times in laravel also.

Comment: @ShaileshMatariya please give me example using sql or eloquent laravel

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 2 warehouse  in sql you could try

```
select distinct item_id, t1._qty qty_warehouse1, t2.qty qty_warehouse1
from my_table m
left  join  (
    select item_id, qty
    from my_table
    where warehouse_id = 1
) t1 on t1.item_id = m.item_id
left  join  (
    select item_id, qty
    from my_table
    where warehouse_id = 2
) t2 on t2.item_id = m.item_id
```

Comment: owh thanks you, I appreciate it. is it possible if i am using eloquent laravel

Comment: i'm not in eloquent  but I assume you can use a raw query

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is to break the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and this is bad practice.

The solution is to have a one to many relation in the table so eloquent can query the result and create the object with the relations you want. 
Adapt your situation to this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909607/laravel-get-a-collection-of-relationship-items)

```
$item->qty_by_warehouses;
```

if you cannot modify the table then

you must get all the items id, 
Loop each one and create an "each_id" object and add to a Result list.

query each id to get warehouse_id and qty and add them to a list
add this list to each_id object.

This will get you the same result as if you have had the eloquent with the one to many relation.